# How to evalute Rule criteria of workflow with Apex Programming?

Tags: apex, workflow, class

I want to evaluate Rule Criteria Expression with Apex Programming. 
For Example :-

Rule Criteria :- 
(Account: Account Name EQUALS ads) AND (Account: Account Number EQUALS 1234)

I want to evaluate this expression and need a boolean result.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This sounds very much like an x-y problem. Also, please do not use irrelevant tags on your questions.

Comment: I think you need to take a few steps back, and really evaluate what you want to do here, and perhaps more importantly, _why_ you want to do it. I don't think you realize the extent of what you're asking. Building an expression evaluator in Apex is possible, but it's far from quick or simple. Your efforts are probably better directed at improving your code so that the extra firing of update triggers (from workflow with field update actions) isn't an issue.

Comment: Why not just write the equivalent of the workflow rule(s) in Apex in the first place? Keeping everything in code would avoid the "second execution" with a lot less work. If you're dead set on writing an evaluator, then I'd use a custom object or custom metadata type instead of workflow. You'll also need to read up on tokenization, context-free grammars, type theory, syntax trees, and tree traversal.

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking is essentially how to reimplement a huge chunk of the Salesforce infrastructure - replacing optimized Salesforce code that can take advantage of a wide variety of techniques and caching solutions not available to you in Apex - with your hand-rolled Apex-based parser and evaluation engine.

That's going to come with a wide variety of consequences.

- It would be a large and highly complex engineering effort.
- It will cost you a chunk of Apex limit to write a fully generalized expression parser and evaluator, which essentially goes to waste.
- You will need to do extensive and complex testing to validate that your code behaves the same way as the native Salesforce workflow evaluation engine. It will be nearly impossible to cover all of the potential cases, opening the door to future regressions.
- You'll have to talk to the Metadata API to obtain workflow definitions and cache them somewhere, which adds more overhead and change management.
- It's unlikely to be as fast as you think. Parsing and text manipulation in general isn't the fastest operation you can perform.
- It may break managed packages (or your own code!) that depend on the standard Salesforce order of execution being followed.

If you're in a situation where your triggers are so expensive to run that two invocations in a transaction will cause CPU time exceptions, this route is highly unlikely to save you, and there are other strategies that are more likely to be successful.

- You *should* focus on reducing the execution time of your triggers and pushing expensive computations and queries into asynchronous code, like Queueables or Batch Apex.
- You might use effective static collection-based recursion guards to avoid processing the same records twice in the same transaction.
- You might reimplement specific workflow rules that run on many or most records of an object as elements of your `before` trigger handlers - not by writing a workflow evaluation engine, but by removing specific workflows and rewriting them in Apex.